# How to append to a div that was just append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to draw multiple lines that contains infos on a product for the exemple lets say its name. I declare the variable at the beginning of my function :

I iterate through a list of product :

```
var productName = '<div class="productName"></div>';

for (var i = 0; i < context._model._productsList.length; i++) {
        var productLine = '<div data-id="' + i + '" class="productLine"></div>';
        $('#boardProducts').append(productLine);
        $('[data-id="' + i + '"]').append(productName);
```

For each product i would like to wrap product name inside the related product name div.

But if i select `$('.productName').append('A name');` it'll select all div productName.

Is there a way to append in the last productName div i did append ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.productName').last().append('A name');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.productName:last').append('A name');
```